# IdentityServer4 fails to authenticate in memory users

Tags: identityserver4

We have an existing ID server configuration and I am trying to work on the UI without having to set up the rest of the connections.  I followed the example to set up an MVC client:

In Startup.cs:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Adding Test Users!!!");
            serviceBulder.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                         .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                         .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                         .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
```

New client added:

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientName = "MVC Client",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                }
            }
```

Users are configured as the following:

```
public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
{
    return new List<TestUser>
    {
        new TestUser
        {
            SubjectId = "1",
            Username = "alice",
            Password = "password"
        },

        new TestUser
        {
            SubjectId = "2",
            Username = "bob",
            Password = "password"
        },
    };
}
```

MVC is configured to use the services:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
            });
    }
```

I have a couple of issues:

1. When I use AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit per tutorial I get  "Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client"
2. When I use the AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid I do get the login screen but my in memory users (alice and bob with pw = password) can't log in.

Questions:
- Does AddTestUsers not work when there are additional data stores present already?
- Why does my grant type differ from the walkthrough?

Comment: Your requested ResponseType of "code id_token" equates to Hybrid, so your Client's `AllowedGrantTypes` must be set to that. You'll need to show us `Config. GetUsers()` to comment further, if it's still not working after that.

Comment: thanks @sellotape - I added the additional information.

Comment: Also, IS has tons of logging; turn it all on for a while and it will tell you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: (I deleted the user password Sha256 comment; think it was incorrect).

Comment: I think since we wrote our own IUserRepository it looks like ID4 doesn't check both the user store and the TempUsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check on the AllowedGrantTypes at the identity server level.  We have roughly the same setup and we use `AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials`  This allows the MVC application to talk with identity server behind the scenes.

The test users should be present.